# Browser using Java not Javascript as DOM manipulation language

Tags: java, javascript, browser

Is/was there a browser that used Java instead of Javascript as it's client-side programming language?

I appreciate that it would have required sites to have multiple versions of their client-side scripting logic as Javascript always seems to have been the dominant language.

Not as an Applet language, but as the language for interacting with the DOM.

I am aware that IE used VBScript for a while.

I am doing a research project on the evolution of the browser and there is so much noise in search engines for these terms that it is difficult to answer this question.

Comment: No AFAIK. Only applets, and good thing they're (mostly) gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) (based on the WebKit) in JavaFX 2 in which you can pass a Java object to JavaScript an call methods on it.

So this can be considered as a browser running on a JVM. Here is an example of how Google Maps are rendered in this browser: [Maps in JavaFX 2.0](http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/).

JS-to-Java call sample: [WebViewSample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/WebViewSample.java.htm).